# C# how can I passing variable acces as expression or text

Tags: c#, expression, ref

I am writing a special compiler for machine controls. On the one hand this should generate machine code from the C# code, on the other hand the same code should be usable for the simmulation.

A memory definition will get an address via a manager (for the machine code), but in the simulation this must contain the value.

In the code sometimes the address must be passed instead of the value. If I have the call (variable name etc.) I can resolve the address myself in the simulation.

Boundary conditions:

- for the transfer I am open for all ideas!!!
- because of array offsets from the old system i have to access the arrays with methods, therefore the method accesses
- to pass them to methods by ref like a direct value, the method must be programmed as 'ref' method
- the code should be adjusted automatically when the variables are changed (e.g. renaming in Visual Studio)

**I have rejected the following approaches:**

**passing as string**

-> does not update on renames, does not compile

```
double addr = getAddress3("Mem.PROBE_SET[1]");
```

**passing as string with nameof**

-> possible, but not easy to use

```
double addr = getAddress3($"{nameof(Mem)}.{nameof(Mem.PROBE_SET)}[1]");

private double getAddress3(string expression)
{
  // Resolve text Expression
  //double addr = MemoryResolver.resolveExpression(expression); 
  return 0.0;
}
```

**My actual Solution, as example code:**

GetAddress2 would be my preferred solution because the call is the same as when I want to address the sepicher as a value and is also very short. Unfortunately I have the 'ref' problem here!
Does anyone have an idea how I could do this better?

```
    public class Test
    {
      private ExampleMemory Mem = new ExampleMemory();

      public Test()
      {
        // booth calls could compile, but no info about anonymus method content in GetAddress
        double addr1 = GetAddress(() => Mem.getProbePos(1));
        double addr2 = GetAddress(() => Mem.PROBE_SET[1]);

        // only addr4 could compile, error CS8153 because ref is used
        //double addr3 = GetAddress2(() => Mem.getProbePos(1)); // Error CS8153
        double addr4 = GetAddress2(() => Mem.PROBE_SET[1]); // Works fine
      }

      private double GetAddress(Func<double> func)
      {
        // no access to source call.... :-( cannot resolve memory
        return 0.0;
      }

      private double GetAddress2(Expression<Func<double>> expr)
      {
        string info = expr.Body.ToString();
        // Infos from Call available => Here i can work with Men.PROBE_SET[1] info and can resolve the memory internally....

        return 0.0;
      }
    }

    public class ExampleMemory
    {
      private int[] PROBE_POS = new int[4];  // with array offset
      public int[] PROBE_SET = new int[4];   // without offset => direct access

      [ArrayOffsetAttribute(Offset = 1)]
      public ref int getProbePos(int index)
      {
        return ref PROBE_POS[index - 1];
      }
    }
```

---

**To summarize again what I have in mind,
a solution for:**

```
        // Work with the memroy value
        var val = Mem.getProbePos(3); // assign e.g. 23

        // Work with address of memory
        var addr = GetAddress(/* ... of Mem.getProbePos(3) ...*/); // assign e.g. control address 1723
```

In the GetAddress method I am free to use anything to get the address. E.g. via reflection of the source assembly of Mem. and so on. But I need the info which memory was called.

I am curious about your ideas and answers!
Thanks a lot in advance.

---

Update to DownloadPizza's question

In the generator, an address is assigned to each field from the memory class *ExampleMemory*. The class then has a starting address e.g. 1300.

The generated iso code from:
`double value = Mem.PROBE_SET[1];`
could then look like this in the ISO, where the MemoryManager assigns an address to a loacal memory address.
`#1 = #1305`

But sometimes the address itself, i.e. the 1305, is used for control functions instead of the value
This is how it **could** look in C#
`CNC.G310(val: value, p: GetAddress(Mem.PROBE_SET[1]), sizeType: "L1");`
and this could be the generated ISO code:
`G310 #1 P 1305 L1`

So i need the behind generated address of my variable, but a address which i had relsoved by my own memory manager. But i need at least the indication which memory (identifier and class as well as the index for arrays) was used.

Comment: I assume you actually need the adress and not just a way to edit a variable thats already defined (if thats the case, try the `ref` keyword). But other than that its not quite clear what you are asking (to me). Are you trying to get the adress of some C# variable? If so you probably need an `unsafe` block and pointers

Comment: Thanks for your input, see above my update.